# Site Data web service requires "Site Collection Administrator" permissions

Tags: permissions, web-services

The Site Data web service requires "Site Collection Administrator" permissions. This seems to be a fairly far-reaching permission to grant. Is there a way to programmatically determine which sites the user the web service client runs under is permissioned to see? Alternatively, for a recursive solution, to see which sub-sites are available under the current one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the Webs webservice and utilize the GetAllSubWebCollection, that should be security trimmed to the user executing the call and not need Full Control permissions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getallsubwebcollection.aspx

Comment: Right. Thanks, will check that out. What is the difference between a "site" and a "web"?